# retrieve data from an existing database and display it in a TextView in android

Tags: android, sqlite

- i have successfully build 2 tables in my `SQLite` for `signup` and
  `UploadBook` for my app where i used the email as linked key between
  the tables and i created one view from the both tables using the
  linked key so now i want to retrieve the `image,Bname,BId` from the
  view to display all the books in list view and then when user click
  the button will load to another activity and display all the
  information about the book using `BId` (book id) .

  here my `SQLite`

  ```
    public class DBConnection extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
          public static final String DbName="RFAll.db";
          SQLiteDatabase db;




              public DBConnection(Context context){
                  super(context,DbName,null,1);

              }
              @Override
              public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                  db.execSQL("create table IF NOT EXISTS UploadBook(BId INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Bname TEXT,Bcategory TEXT,AuthorName TEXT,Bdecs TEXT, Brate REAL, country TEXT,  city TEXT,  address TEXT, phoneno INTEGER,  Email TEXT,  Bprice REAL, Brent REAL,  Bdeposit REAL,   Bimage BLOB ,FOREIGN KEY (Email) REFERENCES signup(Email))");

                  db.execSQL("create table IF NOT EXISTS signup(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Name TEXT,Email TEXT,Password TEXT,REpassword TEXT)");
                  db.execSQL("create VIEW IF NOT EXISTS show as select BId,Bname,Bcategory,AuthorName,Bdecs,Brate,country,city,address,phoneno,Bprice,Brent,Bdeposit,Bimage,ID,signup.Email from signup left join UploadBook on signup.Email=UploadBook.Email");
              }

              @Override
              public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                  db.execSQL("Drop table if EXISTS UploadBook");

                  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS signup");
                  onCreate(db);

              }

              public void insertRow(String Name,String Email,String Password,String REpassword)
              {
                  SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
                  ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();

                  contentValues.put("Name", Name);
                  contentValues.put("Email", Email);
                  contentValues.put("Password", Password);
                  contentValues.put("REpassword", REpassword);

                  db.insert("signup",null,contentValues);

              }
              public void InsertRowUpload(String Bname,String Bcategory,String AuthorName,String Bdecs,Float Brate,String country,String city,String address,Double Phoneno,String Email,Float Bprice,Float Brent ,Float Bdeposit,byte [] Bimage )
              {


                  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

                  contentValues.put("Bname", Bname);
                  contentValues.put("Bcategory", Bcategory);
                  contentValues.put("AuthorName", AuthorName);
                  contentValues.put("Bdecs", Bdecs);
                  contentValues.put("Brate", Brate);
                  contentValues.put("country", country);
                  contentValues.put("city", city);
                  contentValues.put("address", address);
                  contentValues.put("Phoneno", Phoneno);
                  contentValues.put("Email", Email);
                  contentValues.put("Bprice", Bprice);
                  contentValues.put("Brent", Brent);
                  contentValues.put("Bdeposit", Bdeposit);
                  contentValues.put("Bimage", Bimage);

                  db.insert("UploadBook",null,contentValues);


              }





              public void close()
              {
                  db.close();
              }


              public boolean getUser(String email, String pass)
              {

                  String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE Email= '"+ email+"' AND Password = '"+ pass+"' ";


                  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                  // Move to first row
                  cursor.moveToFirst();
                  if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
                  {

                      return true;
                  }
                  cursor.close();
                  db.close();

                  return false;
              }
              public boolean getEmail(String email)
              {

                  String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE  Email= '"+ email+"' ";


                  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                  // Move to first row
                  cursor.moveToFirst();
                 //if (cursor != null)
                  if (cursor.getCount() > 1)
                  {

                      return true;
                  }
                  cursor.close();
                  db.close();

                  return false;
              }
              public boolean getAdmin(String email,String pass)
              {

                  String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE ID=2 AND Email= '"+ email+"' AND Password = '"+ pass+"' ";



                  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                  // Move to first row
                  cursor.moveToFirst();
                  if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
                  {

                      return true;
                  }
                  cursor.close();
                  db.close();

                  return false;
              }

          }
  ```

  and here my `listrow` `html`

  ```
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="100dp"
          android:layout_height="100dp"
          app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
          android:id="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

      <TextView
          android:text="TextView"
          android:layout_width="85dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/txtcost"
          android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txttitle"
          android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txttitle" />

      <TextView
          android:text="TextView"
          android:layout_width="85dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/txttitle"
          android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
          android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
          android:layout_above="@+id/txtcost"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

      <Button
          android:text="MORE"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/butget"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtcost"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtcost"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtcost"
          android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
          android:layout_marginStart="14dp" />

  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

  and here my `listview`

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/activity_main"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      tools:context="com.example.karman.first.MainActivity">

      <ListView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/ListView"
          android:layout_above="@+id/button"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



   </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questioner is asking to implement the app functionality which is too broad. However, I can only provide suggested workflow:

You can write a function which retrieves required info of all the books using a `select query`

```
select Bid, Bname, Bimage from UploadBook
```

Store the results in objects of a `Book class`

```
public Book{
  public Book(int Bid, String Bname, String Bimage){
  }
}
```

Pass the results to your activity.

Use a [listadapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) to display these results in the `ListView`

Handle `Button click` event and initialize `Book activity`. Make a `DB query` to retrieve info of this particular book using `Bid` and display result same as done above.